# Checking integer for input validation of a node

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do my input validation where I have already predefined data in my program. When I want the user to key in a new employee id, I want it to check whether that ID is already in the database, if yes, how do i keep looping it until the user types in an id which is not in the database?

```
struct employee {
    int empNo, salary, performance;
    string name, phoneNo, address, depNo, depName;
    employee* next;
    employee* previous;
} *temp, *head, *tail, *newhead, *newtail, *newnode;
void validate()
{
    cout << "Input not accepted, please try again!" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
}
int main()
{
    int choice = 1;
    int num, salary, performance = 0;
    string name, hpnum, depName, depNo, address;
    bool execute = true;
    insertemployeerecord(0002, "Ethan Tan", 16000, "017-2399193", "Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia", "F001", "Finance", 2);
    insertemployeerecord(0003, "Nikshaen Kumar", 15000, "016-9188131", "Los Angeles, California", "A001", "Audit", 3);
    insertemployeerecord(0001, "Koughen Mogan", 17500, "014-1233241", "Los Angeles, California", "F001", "Finance", 4);
    while (execute)
    {
        cout << "..........................................................." << endl;
        cout << "                    EMERGE EMPLOYEE SYSTEM                 " << endl;
        cout << "..........................................................." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "1. Add an Employee Record" << endl;
        cout << "2. Display All Records" << endl;
        cout << "3. Search by Employee ID" << endl;
        cout << "4. Search by Employee overall performance" << endl;
        cout << "5. Sort and display by Employee ID in ascending order" << endl;
        cout << "6. Sort and display by Employee Salary in ascending order " << endl;
        cout << "7. Sort and display by Employee Overall Performance in ascending order " << endl;
        cout << "8. Modify an Employee Record" << endl;
        cout << "9. Delete an Employee Record" << endl;
        cout << "10. Calculate salary package of an employee" << endl;
        cout << "11. Exit" << endl;
        cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Select your option: ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Enter employee number: ";
        cin >> num;
        while (!cin >> num) //to see if user types anything besides number
        {
            validate();
            cout << "Enter employee number: ";
            cin >> num;
        }
        temp = head;
        bool verify = true;
        if (temp != NULL)
        {
            while (temp->empNo != num)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
                if (temp == NULL)
                {
                    verify = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (verify == true)  //if the user types an id that is found in the database
            {
                validate();
                cout << "Employee found in database!" << endl;
                cout << "Enter employee number: " << endl;
                cin >> num;
            }
            if (verify == false)
            {
                cin.get();
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter employee name: ";
        getline(cin, name);
```

As you can see, my output can detect if there is an alphabet being typed and also if the user types an id thats already in the database, but when I type a new id, example being 4, the system still says it detects from the database

```
Enter employee number: a
Input not accepted, please try again!
Enter employee number: 1
Input not accepted, please try again!
Employee found in database!
Enter employee number:
2
Input not accepted, please try again!
Employee found in database!
Enter employee number:
3
Input not accepted, please try again!
Employee found in database!
Enter employee number:
4
Input not accepted, please try again!
Employee found in database!
```

Comment: Where is define `temp` and  `head` variables ?

Comment: In your code you need only one while loop.

Comment: Maybe you got stuck in this loop ` while (verify == true)  //if the user types an id that is found in the database`

Comment: @MatthieuH i have revised the code for my temp and head defining variables

Comment: @NikitaSmirnov if i use if verify == true, the system only detects the error once, not multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```cpp
int enter_employee_number() {
    int number;
    do{
        cout << "Enter employee number: ";
        cin >> number;
        bool fail = cin.fail();
        if(fail)
            cout << "Input not accepted, please try again!" << endl;
     } while (fail);
     return number;
}

string enter_employee_name() {
    string name;
    do{
        cout << "Enter employee name: ";
        cin >> name;
        bool fail = cin.fail();
        if(fail)
            cout << "Input not accepted, please try again!" << endl;
     } while (fail);
     return name;
}

employee get_employee(int number) {
    // retrieve your employee and return it.
}

int main() {
    // other part of your code
    if (choice == 1) {
        system("cls");
        while(true) {
            int empNo = enter_employee_number();
            employee emp = get_employee();
            if (emp != nullptr) {
                cout << "Employee found in database!" << endl;
                string empName = enter_employee_name();
                // call method that use empName
            }
            else {
                cout << "Employee not found in database!" << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in your code i see that when it says employee found in database,it doesnt reject the input, what I want to do it when a person keys an id that is already in the database, it it supposed to decline and ask the user to find a new one

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way of input validation is via getting everything in a string, like define  `string inputLine` and use `std::getline()` and then parsing it using `std::istringstream(inputLine)`. If you want to continue till validation succeeds, put below code in loop.

```
        if ( stringStream >> ID >> std::ws && stringStream.get() == EOF)
            //At this point you have Employee Id in ID variable , Now you can do database check.
            if(validate(ID)) // if validation succeeds.
                break; // Break out of loop, otherwise continue till you get correct input.
```